# How can I output a string in Ember while still having it interpreted by handlebars?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Here's a simple example

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  content: "some @user",
  parsedContent: function() {
    return this.get("content").replace("@user", "<a {{action gotoUser 'user'}}>user</a>");
  }.property("content")
});
```

which will output

```
some @user
some <a {{action gotoUser 'user'}}>user</a>
```

instead of interpreting the content as a Handlebars template. I guess I need to compile this manualy, but I'm not sure how to pass the correct context.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darthdeus/6p6XJ/228/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleypriest/6p6XJ/250/).
Basically by making the template of a view a computed property you can modify the template before passing it into the Handlebars parser.

```
MyApp.LinkedUsersView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: function() {
        template = this.get("content").replace(/@(\w+)/g, '{{view MyApp.UserLinkView username="$1"}}');
        return Ember.Handlebars.compile(template);
    }.property()
});

MyApp.UserLinkView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: "span",
    user: function() {
        return MyApp.User.findByUsername(this.get('username'));
    }.property(),
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<a {{action goToUser view.user href=true}}>@{{view.username}}</a>')
}); 

{{view MyApp.LinkedUsersView content="some @user with @another_user"}}
```

I'm not sure of the performance of compiling the Handlebars template every time though.

Comment: While it seems to work, it doesn't data-bind. Try doing `MyApp.get("router.applicationController").set("content", "whatever")` in the JSFiddle, it won't re-render the template.

Comment: Again, a performance thing, the quick fix is to change the handlebars to `{{#with content}}
    {{view MyApp.LinkedUsersView contentBinding="this"}}
  {{/with}}`

Comment: Or you could create an observer which rerender's the view when the content change. http://jsfiddle.net/bradleypriest/6p6XJ/253/

Comment: Yeah the observer seems to work, but any idea why the `.property("content")` doesn't work by itself? I thought it binds to the change in the same way that observers do